# List routes in a Rails 2 project

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

How can I get the list of routes programatically in a rails 2 project. In a Rails 3 project, 
`Rails.application.routes.routes` did what I wanted. But when I try this on a Rails 2 web site. It fails with the message `No application method defined on Rails object`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can look at the code for rake routes tasks most probably under

```
/gems/rails/2.3.x/lib/tasks/routes.rake for Rails 2. 

ActionController::Routing::Routes.routes
```

look at the rake task in more detail to get a better Idea

Comment: Im not able to find the path /gems/rails/... Is that the full path ?

Comment: it depends where you have your gems installed

Answer (score 1):

you can try,

```
rake routes
```

this gives all the routes

UPDATE:

or on `Rails 3+`

```
bundle exec rake routes
```